# How to show real-time data from socket.io to yii2 gridview without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on yii2 and socket.io where i need to show real-time data on gridview without refresh the page.

Gridview should be update once anything updates in database. Pagination & filters should work along with them.

Also pjax will not help me, because i have millions of records and i do not want to refresh the gridview.

Any Help would be great. Thanks

```html
socket.on('refresh feed',function(msg){
            // $.pjax.reload({container: '#pjax-grid-view'});

             var table = $('#gridview-id table tbody');

            var number= parseInt($("#w0-container table tbody tr:first").attr('id')) +1;

            var class_name = ((table.find('tr').length)%2 === 0)?'odd':'even';
            var html = '<tr id="'+ number +'" class="'+number+'"> <td>'+number+'</td><td>'+msg+'</td><td>(not set)</td> </tr>';

            table.prepend(html);


        });
```

Comment: You want a live connection between the database and the webpage? Using millions of records? I would suggest starting with the Socket.io examples and see if you understand the basics. Then read about DOM manipulation using Javascript. If you get stuck with specific code you can post your code problem here!

Comment: Yes, i already created demo where i m able to get realtime data using emit the channel to gridview using jquery, but when i add rows in gridview i need to updates pagination for gridview as all rows are getting added in same page. Please check my code to add rows in gridview.

Comment: is there any way to change gridview pagination without pjax or refresh?

Comment: Ah, in that case I would just use  `document.createElement` when the socket supplies new information. This way you can alter your HTML layout without reloading the page.